# Как присвоить класс через n одинаковых элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Допустим у меня на странице каталога есть 200 одинаковых элементов с одинаковым классом.
Как мне с помощью js добавить новый класс через n элементов. Предположим через 8, т.е. добавить новый класс 1, 9, 17, 25 ... - элементу ?

Comment: А почему не через CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без всяческих джикверей:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.some-class'); 
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length - 8; i += 8) 
  elements[i].classList.add('another-class');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassname(oneClass);
      for (var i=0||1||etc; i<=elements.length; i+=8) 
         {element[i].setAttribute(class, onePerEight)};
```

Comment: Позвольте узнать что за метод `setAttr`? В JS - `setAttribute`, в jQuery - `attr`.

Comment: поправил, понадеялся на память, а она подвела...

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант, разбил по шагам для понимания (можно упороться и засунуть в одну функцию)

1 выбрать все элементы

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
```

2 выбрать каждый 8-й

```
var b = [].filter.call(a, function(item, i){return i%8 == 0});
```

3 присвоить выбранным доп класс

```
b.forEach(function(el){ el.classList.add('new-class')});
```

Comment: Я упоролся: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.card')].forEach((e, i) => i % 8 === 0 ? e.classList.add('some') : null)`.

Comment: @Other +1 )))))

Answer (score 0):

```
var $elements = $(".odinakovyjKlass");
for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i = i + 8) {
  $elements.eq(i).addClass("drugojKlass");
}
```

@LeonidMyronov напомнил про `filter`:

```
$(".odinakovyjKlass").filter(index => !(index % 8)).addClass("drugojKlass");
```

Comment: ))) Значит в правильном направлении думаю)))